# Trigger List Workflow Using Form Action Button

Tags: 2013, workflow

I am using SharePoint Designer to customise a 'new' form.

I would like it to include a form action button that triggers a list workflow. I can easily get it to trigger a site workflow but not list. Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you don't want the workflow to start on any item creation but only if this specific button is pushed. I'm also assuming you're referring to the Form Actions button you can insert when editing the .aspx form in SharePoint (which creates and associates a specific Site Workflow). 
I have had a similar requirement from an edit form and learned that SP 2013 list workflows cannot be programmatically started like this. You can have that site workflow trigger SP 2010 workflows if those will meet your needs. I ultimately used a button object (which had type="button" rather than submit), which set a yes/no field and then triggered the submit action. My workflow ran on item creation and checked for this value, if yes-run, if not-end workflow.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Yes, I don't want the workflow to start on any item creation. I would like it to start once the button has been hit. Correct me if this isn't what you meant meant, but I'm unable to use site workflows on 'current' items, so triggering a site workflow isn't an option. A button that will set a yes/no field  would be perfect though. Could you explain how you did this (in detail!) please. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is from an old version, but the pattern may still work.

https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/10/sharepoint-launch-site-workflow-from.html